# How do I split hostas?

Tags: transplanting, hosta

I have some hosta plants that are getting quite large and are crowded where they are located right now. What do I need to worry about when moving/splitting hostas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't know if this is the best technique but here is what I did and it worked :)

Go all around the clump pushing in a shovel as far as it will go.  You should now be able to pry/lift the plant out of the hole with the root/dirt ball intact.  Work the shovel down between the plant stems to slice/pry them apart trying to keep as many of the roots attached to their stems as possible.  I divided the root ball into quarters leaving a generous clump (5-10) of stems with lots of roots still attached for planting.

Comment: This method worked for me as well.  The best time to move hostas is late summer/early fall or spring.

Comment: They're pretty tough - I ended up using an axe to split one of mine, and judging from the results it thrives on abuse.

Comment: I use an old hand saw to split plants. Sure, it cuts some roots, but it's pretty non-damaging to everything but the actual cut portion.

Comment: When using relatively decent soil conditions (ie. not sand) I have yet to succeed in "killing" a hosta by splitting, moving, or replanting one. I have literally handled thousands over the 8+ years as a landscaper. Sure, leaves may die or wilt in the initial season, but EVERY year they continue to pop back up. Have at it and split away with a spade, axe, shovel, your hands, trowel, edger...