# Do Hosta grow from root segment?

Tags: propagation, hosta

I've successfully split rhubarb by root segment, but have never tried splitting a Hosta by a root cutting. Would this work for Hosta like it does Rhubarb?

Comment: Yes, you can! There is a question about how to do it here:  [How do I split hostas?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/558/how-do-i-split-hostas)